# Contract CodeRejected when using chain extension

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts, chain-extension

I've recently upgraded my chain to the latest substrate master, however, I'm unable to deploy contracts that use a chain extension. When I try to use a chain extension, the contract fails to deploy with the `CodeRejected` error. Are there any breaking changes in the chain extension configuration that I may have missed when upgrading?

My contract code is here: https://github.com/ideal-lab5/contracts/blob/main/iris_asset_exchange/lib.rs

And my chain extension is defined here: https://github.com/driemworks/substrate/blob/f73557b96ef8c7cc1e428a78ea4106b66c165d64/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L920

As you can see, I have defined that the chain extension should be enabled:

```
fn enabled() -> bool {
    true
}
```

I encountered the same issue when trying to use the rand-extension example too: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/rand-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell `pallet-contracts` about your chain extensions [here](https://github.com/driemworks/substrate/blob/f73557b96ef8c7cc1e428a78ea4106b66c165d64/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L314).

You need to do this:

```rust
type ChainExtension = IrisExtension;
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! I modified the runtime to include that and my contract deploys successfully now.